# Use XML file as database

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

How can I use a XML file as a database and execute some basic SELECT command only on it !
ex: **select author from file.xml where title="MyTitle"**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
</book>
<book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
</book>
</catalog>
```

*I've never worked with XML file (as DB) so have no code to put here, but hope someone have some solution !*

Comment: What options have you explored? What has your research come up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into XPath.  The `System.XML.XmlDocument.SelectNodes` method allows you to select matching nodes via XPath.  It's not SQL, but it's a common way to find nodes in an XML document.  The following example uses XPath to retrieve the authors of all the books with a title of "Midnight Rain".

```
    Dim document As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    document.Load("file.xml")
    Dim matches As XmlNodeList = document.SelectNodes("/catalog/book[title = 'Midnight Rain']/author")
    For Each node As XmlNode In matches
        'Do work
    Next
```

Comment: XPath should be replaced with LINQ to XML if .Net 3.5 or above.

Comment: :)  I've never been a big fan of LINQ, but to each their own.  XPath is an open standard that is used in many tools and languages, so it's useful to learn, regardless.

Comment: I'm with @SteveDog on this one... LINQ is sometimes just overkill.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can simply use SQL against XML, not without quite a lot of work (a SQL parser that can translate to your XML structure using an XML parser).

The closest you can get is to use LINQ to XML with the [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class and [`System.Xml.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195.aspx) namespace.

Comment: A little bit of code will be highly appreciated for LINQ to XML :)

Comment: @Sourav: You can get some samples at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.100).aspx